# on getting the value of a radio button

Tags: jquery

I would like to ask what's wrong with this code, it seems legit to me.

When I select the radio button, my `radioMininum` still remains `0`.

```
var radioMinimum=0;

$('#mMininum').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            radioMinimum = 1;
            alert(radioMinimum);
        }
        else{
            radioMinimum=0;
            alert(radioMinimum);
        }
});

alert(radioMinimum);
```

inside the if-else the radioMinimum displays correctly. like if checked,its 1.
but the bottom alert-outside .click radioMinimum still displays 0.

Comment: This isn't php, it is jquery...

Comment: duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery/32182172#32182172

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

### Everything appears to be working as expected:

```js
var radioMinimum = 0;

$('#mMininum').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            radioMinimum = 1;
            console.log(radioMinimum);
        }
        else{
            radioMinimum=0;
            console.log(radioMinimum);
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mMininum">Minimum</input>
```

Comment: but if i display the radioMinimum after the .click it displays 0 still

Comment: @phloxangrex you can't bind a .click to something that doesn't exist.  please use `$(document).ready(function() {//code here});` or just add it before the `</body>` tag.